# Ignore missing data frames when using rbind.fill on a list of data frames

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have many data frames which are usually in the format `file.[i]`, but occasionally there are missing data frames:

```
file.1 file.2 file.3 file.4 file.5 file.6 file.7 file.9 file.11 file.13
```

What I tried to do is this:

```
 dt <- do.call(rbind.fill, 
              lapply(paste("file.", 1:length(filenames), sep=""), get))
```

And I get:

```
Error in FUN(c("file.1", "file.2", "file.3", "file.4", "file.5", "file.6",  : 
  object 'file.8' not found
```

Is there a way to make `rbind.fill` ignore the missing data frames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
obj.names <- paste0("file.", seq_along(filenames))
dt <- rbind.fill(mget(Filter(exists, obj.names)))
```

Comment: you can also use `mget(obj.names,ifnotfound=list(data.frame()))`

Comment: Or perhaps something like `mget( ls( pattern = "^file.[0-9]+$" ) )`

Comment: Also `rbind.fill` takes a list, so you don't need `do.call`